# How to set a generic constraint that the type is a List?

Tags: c#, generics

```
private static void PrintEachItemInList<T>(T anyList) 
Where T:System.Collections.Generic.List<T>
{    
    foreach (var t in T)
    {
        //Do whatever
    }
}
```

In the above code (which is wrong) all I want to do it to set a constraint that `T` is a List.

The aim is not to get this example to work, the aim is to understand how can I set a constraint that the type is a list? I am an amateur in generics and am trying to figure things out :(

Comment: How do you define "list"? `IList<T>` or `List<T>`? The latter is most likely a bad choice for a generic constraint. Or would `IEnumerable<T>` be enough?

Comment: (Either one is fine, however I would prefer IList<T>

Comment: Your convention is for your parameter is confusing, `T anyType` is actually `T anyListType`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you want *two* type parameters, as in:

```
private static void PrintEachItemInList<TList, TItem>(TList anyType) 
  where TList : System.Collections.Generic.List<TItem>
```

This is useful if you use classes that actually derive from `List<>`. If you want anything that *acts* as a list, consider constraining to the *interface* `IList<>` instead. It will then work for `List<>`, single-dimensional arrays, and custom classes implementing the interface (but not necessarily deriving from `List<>`).

**Edit:** As pointed out by the comment, this method is cumbersome to use because the compiler will not infer the two type arguments, so they will have to be given explicitly when calling the method.

Consider just using:

```
private static void PrintEachItemInList<TItem>(List<TItem> anyType)
```

Because anything which derives from a `List<>` is assignable to `List<>`, the method can be called with derived classes as arguments, and in many cases the type `TItem` can be inferred automatically by the compiler.

Still consider using the interface `IList<>`.

If all you want to do, is *read* from the list, use `IReadOnlyList<TItem>` instead of `IList<TItem>`. This signals to the caller that you won't change his list. Still no cast syntax is required when calling, for example: `PrintEachItemInList(new[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, });`. The type `IReadOnlyList<>` is new in .NET version 4.5.

If all you want to do is read from the list, and you don't want to use the indexer (no `anyType[idx]`), and you don't want to use the `.Count` property, and in fact, all you want to do is `foreach` through the list, use `IEnumerable<TItem>`. Again, you signal that you won't change people's lists.

Both `IReadOnlyList<>` and `IEnumerable<>` are *covariant* in their generic argument (type parameter).

Comment: he,you beat me to it... +1

Comment: I'm sorry, but this code requires you to specify generic arguments explicitly (no type inference) to call this method `PrintEachItemInList<List<int>, int>(new List<int>{1,2,3});`

Answer (score 6):

Declare your input parameter as `IList<T>`. If you want to make your input sequence as abstract as possible - use `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IList<T>`

```
private static void PrintEachItemInList<T>(IList<T> sequence)
{
    foreach (T element in sequence)
    {
        //Do whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: I am aware of this, but what i want to know how do I set this as a constraint on T.

Comment: What constraints are used for? To restrict closed types, that can be applied to a open type. In case given above input types are restricted to IList<T>. This is the way how extension methods are implemented in LINQ

Comment: @developer747 Wouldn't this be setting the constraint on T, since it can only be of any type wrapped in IList?  Or am I missing an additional requirement of yours?  +1

Answer (score 3):

Your function should simply accept a list, and you don't need a constraint:

```
private static void PrintEachItemInList<T>(IList<T> list) 
{
    foreach (var t in list)
    {
        //Do whatever
    }
}
```

However, if you only want to iterate the list you can make your code more general by changing the parameter type to one of these base interfaces:

- `IEnumerable<T>` - allows `foreach`
- `IReadOnlyCollection` - same as above and provides the count of elements in the collection
- `IReadOnlyList` - same as above and allows element access by index
- `ICollection<T>` - an `IEnumerable<T>` that provides an element count and methods to add and remove elements
- `IList<T>` - same as above and allows you to add and remove elements by index

Comment: +1 for clear distinction between three fundamental interfaces in .net

Comment: I think this answer has an issue if the user also has defined a signature which is NOT for a list. The list<T> version will never be invoked.    


For instance if there was also a sig for:   


`private static void PrintEachItemInList<T>(T instance) `

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use parametric polymorphism to express that constraint, in c# you need two type parameters (since you don't get higher-order types):

```
private static void PrintEachItemInList<X, T>(X anyType) where X:System.Collections.Generic.List<T>
{

             foreach (var t in anyType)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
            }
}
```

but then you need to call like this:

```
PrintEachItemInList<List<string>,string>(new List<string>() {"a", "b"});
```

Comment: @DavidL this is one of the few cases where reified generics actually don't help... In java you can express this with wildcards, like `public void PrintEachItemInList(List<?> anyType)`

Answer (score 1):

You would typically write this as:

```
private static void PrintEachItemInList<T>(List<T> anyType)
{
  // do work
}
```

However, in this case, I would recommend using `IEnumerable<T>` instead:

```
private static void PrintEachItemInList<T>(IEnumerable<T> anyType)
{
  // do work
}
```

This will still allow you to use `foreach` but allow your method to be more flexible, as it will work work `List<T>` but also any other collection which implements `IEnumerable<T>`.  If you must have list semantics within the method, you could use `IList<T>` , but your sample code (and method name) suggests `IEnumerable<T>` would be more appropriate.