# How to get the type constraint list from INamedTypeSymbol

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn

I have a type that comes as **INamedTypeSymbol**, his definition like this:

```
    public interface IFoo<TFoo> where TFoo: class
    {
        TFoo Foo{ get; set; }
    }
```

How can I get the constraint list? (here is: **where TFoo: class**)

Comment: Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816880/how-to-set-a-generic-constraint-that-the-type-is-a-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INamedTypeSymbol has a `TypeParameters` which will get you to `TFoo`, that type parameter symbol has various properties (`ConstraintTypes`, `HasReferenceTypeConstraint`, etc.) to see what constraints exist.